# Send UDP packet to fpga spartan 3e via ethernet

Tags: udp, ethernet, fpga, microblaze, spartan

I want to send UDP packet to fpga which includes microblaze. But i have a problem about ip address. Where can i get the ip address of fpga.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign a static IP for the mac address and use that IP in your FPGA code for filtering n etc.,If your board is not on any network say one to one Ethernet to your computer then just VHDL coding would do.

Answer (score 0):

Your FPGA itself does not have an IP address. 
If you have an evaluation/prototyping board there often is a sticker with the MAC address assigned to this board.
Everything regarding IP address processing and UDP port numbers is up to you and has to be implemented either as logic on the FPGA itself or as software for the Microblaze.